# I want to return response to download CSV file from data frame contains Arabic letters

Tags: python, html, dataframe, csv, flask

I have encountered a problem while coding using Flask for my website
I have a CSV file that I converted to Dataframe then I want to return it as CSV to the user so they can download it.

however, when I do that the Arabic letters do not show clearly only symbols :( I tried different possible ways but unfortunately, all doesn't work

```py
@flask_app.route('/getPlotCSV')
def download_file():
    path ="marked_test_df.csv"
    #path.encode('utf-8-sig')
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8-sig')
        df_ob= df.to_csv(encoding='utf-8-sig')
        resp = make_response(df_ob)
        resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=marked_test_df.csv "
        #resp.charset='utf-8-sig'
        #resp.iter_encoded='utf-8-sig'
        resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv ; charset = utf-16"
        resp.content_encoding = 'utf-16'
        os.remove(path)
    except Exception as error:
        flask_app.logger.error("Error removing or closing downloaded file handle", error)

    return resp
```

[sample of the CSV before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wQgV.png) the user can download it:

However, when the user downloads it through the download button [it shows like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV8R6.png):

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Encoding of non-English text is a chain that can break in many places. Could you post a sample of the CSV you upload, and the CSV users download ? This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll add on my original question sample of the CSV so it would make it clearer

Comment: Could you please *avoid* putting samples files as an image ? The best way to help in encoding matters is to look at the bytes available. As a trivial example, a 1 line file containing 4 chinese characters can appear in probably 10+ different ways without being changed any way. Just depends how the content is presented (encoding selected).  SO, please use pastebin or similar. The relevant for you are the bytes containing the arab text. You can also put as binary in your post, like this: `E5 89 C3 ...`  (random selection to show example).